# rotation of image by mouse in c#

Tags: c#

I want to rotate/move image as per mouse movement.when right button of mouse is pressed ,image move to right and when button released movement of image should stop,same apply for left button.how to do that in windows programming(without using wpf)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rotate a picture in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi Prit, welcome to StackOverflow. You might not get many answers unless you say what you've tried, and how that's not worked, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about how to rotate images in winforms applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp)

And example of mouse up/mouse down events [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320945/winforms-listview-mouseup-event-firing-more-than-once) or at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx)